# Thread1: Exc_Bad_Instruction?

Tags: swift

I can't figure out why am I keep getting this Thread: Error message when running this program.

```
    let textLabelOriginX = self.checkboxSideLength + 5.0
    _ = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - textLabelOriginX, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))
    let myNSString: NSString = NSString(string: ((self.textLabel.text))!)
    let textLabelSize:CGSize =  myNSString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: self.textLabel.font])
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(textLabelOriginX, (CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - textLabelSize.height) / 2.0, textLabelSize.width, textLabelSize.height))
```

error this line ==> `let myNSString: NSString = NSString(string: ((self.textLabel.text))!)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is because the textLabel has not been setup yet. If this code is being called very early in a view controller's lifecycle for example, outlets will not yet be setup, causing all of their linked instance variables to still be nil. If that's the case then `self.textLabel.text` will be `nil`, and force-unwrapping it with the `!` will crash.

If this doesn't seem like it fits your situation, then please post a larger portion of the code for review.